# Bayesian Regression with ARIMA errors

Tags: r, bayesian, estimation, arima, software

Is there a framework (e.g. R package) which allows for Bayesian estimation of dynamic regression models with AR(I)MA errors (similar to the frequentist implementation in the `forecast` package in R, e.g. `auto.arima`).

My goal is to impose priors on the external regressors. So the model looks like

$y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1, t} + ... + \beta_k x_{k, t} + \eta_t$,

$\eta_t = \phi_t \eta_{t-1} + ... + \phi_p \eta_{t-p} - \theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1} - ... - \theta_q \epsilon_{t-q} + \epsilon_t$

where the regressor coefficients can have priors, e.g. $\beta_1 \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ or $\beta_2 \sim Beta(a_2, b_2)$.

Is this the same as a Bayesian Structural Time Series model (as implemented in the R package `bsts`)?

Or should I use a framework for Bayesian models like `Stan` or `greta`? Are these even suited for time series modelling?

Comment: Regressions with ARIMA errors are an example of a linear Gaussian state space model. There are many R packages that can compute the posterior for such models, with varying degrees of ability to customize priors. The CRAN Task View for time series is probably the best place to start. You can use Stan for time series data; there are several such examples in its documentation (section 2 in the user's guide).

Comment: Thank you! I am a bit confused about the terminology "State Space Model", "Dynamic Regression" and "Structural Model". Are these just different terms for the same model? Any suggestions which package to use in particular? I had a close look at `bsts`, `bssm`, `dlm` and `brms`, but cannot find a function to express regressions with ARIMA errors. With Stan though it should be possible to implement, I am currently trying this.